# PlayReady Company Certificates for testing

Tags: security, certificate, playready

I am writing a tool suite that, among other things, must support PlayReady Model Certificate generation from various Device Company CA certificates (which we will receive from customers).

In order to properly test the software end-to-end I need to obtain some test Company certificates. I could not find the relevant information in PlayReady documentation that was provided by Microsoft. Is there a way to obtain such certificates easily?

(Thinking about it, there probably should exist a root certificate for testing purposes only - I could not find any info on that as well)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for can be found in a subdirectory below the 'test' directory of the source code that is provided when you install the Microsoft PlayReady Device Porting Kit (PK).  If you do not have this Device PK MSI installer (perhaps you only have the Microsoft PlayReady Certificate Generation Kit MSI), then I recommend that you contact Microsoft to legally obtain a copy of the latest PlayReady Device PK MSI.

If you have PlayReady Device PK 2.0.0:

- If you need it, a test root certificate is located here:
  `c:\PlayReady\Device_PK_2.0.0\test\ToolTests\files\rootcert.dat`
- There are some example test group/model certificates (bgroupcert*), and their associated test private keys (zgpriv*), are located here: `C:\PlayReady\Device_PK_2.0.0\test\devicedevcert\`
- There are also some example files that you may find informative in the `C:\PlayReady\Device_PK_2.0.0\Samples\` sub-directory, such as:

  - SampleDACResponsePR.dat
  - SampleDACResponseWMDRMPD.xml
  - SamplePrivKeys.xml
- It looks like there are also some potentially useful files in the `C:\PlayReady\Device_PK_2.0.0\test\certs\files` sub-directory, such as:

  - companyprivkey.xml
  - companypubkeymodulusb64.txt
  - rootprivkey.xml
  - rootpubkeymodulusb64.txt
  - testrootprivkey.dat
  - testrootpubkey.dat
  - unsignedtemplate.xml

That said, you should be able to use the following tools, and some of the files above, to simulate/test the full certificate request and generation process:

- `C:\PlayReady\Device_PK_2.0.0\Tools\generatecompanycertrequest.exe`
- `C:\PlayReady\Device_PK_2.0.0\Tools\generatekeypair.exe`
- `C:\PlayReady\Device_PK_2.0.0\Tools\generatemodelcert.exe`

Note: Since PlayReady certificate chains are in "binary" format (i.e. not XML), you will need to use `bcertdump` to view them, similar to: `c:\PlayReady\Device_PK_2.0.0\Tools\bcertdump.exe -b:.\rootcert.dat -v`

Also, if/when you have PlayReady Device PK 2.5.0, things may be organized (and work) slightly differently.

Comment: I do have a legal copy of PlayReady Device Porting Kit Version 2.0.0. There are 53 subdirectories under test. Can you please be more specific as to what to look for? Thank you.

Comment: Excellent!  I have edited my answer to include requested details.

Comment: I am accepting your answer, although I still do not have what I need:

I was able to use the code in test/certs to generate what seems to be a customer certificate. However, that certificate is in XML form. What I need is a binary certificate chain (that starts with 'CHAI') that I can feed to generatemodelcert.exe . I will prowl around the code to see if that is possible.

Comment: Make sure that you specify the `-z:PR` option when using the `generatemodelcert.exe` tool.  That option tells it to generate PlayReady a certificate chain. (I thought that option was the default, which is why I did not mention it.)  Check out the full help `/?` on that command for all the options/parameters.

Comment: -z is not my problem; -b is

Comment: The test PlayReady binary certificate chain [containing just a test company certificate (SL150, cert #1) + the PlayReady root certificate (SL2000, cert #2)] that you want to use is in the file `SampleDACResponsePR.dat`.  Use that file with the `-b` parameter of `generatemodelcert.exe` to create a model/group certificate chain.  I think that should do it...  :)